# Estimate for the power of a integral

Tags: calculus

Let $T \geq 0.$
Is it true and how can you prove that for every $p \geq2$ we have

$$\left( \int_0^T |f(x)| \mathrm{\ d}x\right)^p \leq T^{p-1} \int_0^T |f(x)|^p \mathrm{\ d}x?$$

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Lebesgue_measure

Answer (score 1):

This follows immediately from Holder's inequality: $$\int_0^T |f(x)| dx \leq \left(\int_0^T 1 \ dx \right)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\left( \int_0^T |f(x)|^p dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$ Taking both sides to the $p$ power gives the required result since $x \mapsto x^p$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Can you give the OP a little more push (Which two functions to use for example?)

Answer (score 0):

we can write it like this :
$\int_{0}^{T}\left | f(x) \right |dx\leq  T^{\frac{p-1}{p}}.(\int_{0}^{T}\left | f(x) \right |^{p}dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\$
so use Holder inequality :
$\int_{0}^{T}\left | f(x) \right |dx\leq(\int_{0}^{T}1.dx\leq)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}.(\int_{0}^{T}\left | f(x) \right |^{p}dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}=T^{\frac{p-1}{p}}.\left \| f \right \|_{p}\\with :\left \| f \right \|_{p}=(\int_{0}^{T}\left | f(x) \right |^{p}dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$